# How do i activate a worksheet from a workbook that i have already opened previously based on cell text from my current workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How do i activate the worksheet of the workbook that i have already opened previously based on cell text from my current workbook? For instance, I tried to use the code below to activate the worksheet deviceB in "Book1" where i have already opened from the current workbook that i am using called "anotherworkbook" but it says subscript out of range when clearly the worksheet device B exists in "Book1".

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text).Activate 

'trying to activate the worksheet device B in "Book1" from another workbook that i am currently using called "anotherworkbook"
```

**Workbook called book1 that i have already opened where i am trying to activate the worksheet lets say device B based on cell text from my current workbook called "anotherworkbook"**

[image]

**Current workbook that i am using called "anotherworkbook"**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Activate the workbook.
Then Activate the worksheet on that workbook. 
*(Then Activate the Range on that worksheet, if desired)*

**EDIT#1:**

Here is some working code.  Assumes:

1. master.xlsm is `ThisWorkbook` and contains the macros
2. master.xlsm has a worksheet named *Device B*
3. Book1.xlsx has a single sheet and in cell **A2** of that sheet is the text *Device B*

   ```
   Sub Routine()
   Dim databook As Workbook, s As String

   Set databook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\TestFolder\Book1.xlsx")
   s = databook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text

   ThisWorkbook.Activate
   Worksheets(s).Activate
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: but book1 is the workbook where i run originally first run my vba code so isnt it already activated? Because my programme will eventually create a workbook called "anotherworkbook" so this is where i am currently at and i trying to activate the worksheet "device B" based on the cell text in the sheet1 of the orignial workbook book 1 from my current workbook "anotherworkbook" but i keep getting the subscript out of range error..

Comment: like i don't understand the part on "Then Activate the worksheet on that workbook" like isn't ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text).Activate referring to activating the worksheet device B on my  original workbook "book1" even though i am currently at "Anotherworkbook"?

Comment: @john  In general, if a workbook is not active, then you cannot activate a sheet on that workbook.

Comment: So if i use  Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text).Activate to activate worksheet device B in book1 from "anotherworkbook", does it works? Because i did something similar to this before and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @john Also *Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text* will get text from whatever workbook.is active.

Comment: @john  Again **Activate the book and then Activate the sheet on separate VBA lines of code.**

Comment: @john  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks, i get your idea!